# One to One relation is not working on TypeORM

Tags: javascript, typescript, orm, typeorm

I have two models which is reference with One-to-One relation.

```
@Entity()
class Restaurant {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({
        type: 'varchar',
        length: 1000,
        unique: true
    })
    name: string;

    @Column()
    @OneToOne(() => RestaurantType)
    @JoinColumn()
    restaurantType: RestaurantType;
}
```

```
@Entity()
class RestaurantType {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({nullable: false})
    resturantType: string;

    @Column({
        type: 'time with time zone', 
        default: Date.now()
    })
    createdAt: Date;
}
```

But I am seeing this error when running the server,

```
DataTypeNotSupportedError: Data type "RestaurantType" in "Restaurant.restaurantType" is not supported by "postgres" database.
```

Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove `@Column()` decorator from `restaurantType` property of `Restaurant` entity.

```
@Entity()
class Restaurant {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({
        type: 'varchar',
        length: 1000,
        unique: true
    })
    name: string;

    @OneToOne(() => RestaurantType)
    @JoinColumn()
    restaurantType: RestaurantType;
}
```

For additional information about `OneToOne` relations please refer to the [docs](https://typeorm.io/#/one-to-one-relations).